# Separate every line with a space on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Assuming I have a list like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

What would I have to do to change it to:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

Answer (score 2):

Click the following starting at the menu:

1. Edit
2. Blank Operations
3. EOL to Space

[image]

Comment: I've used Notepad++ for years and I still discover useful things

Answer (score 0):

Open replace window by `ctrl+h` or through menu,
Find what: `\n`
Replace with: 
Check below `Extended` or `Regular Expression` in `Search Mode`,
Then click `Replace All`.

Depend on the situation, you might need change the `Find what:` part to `\r\n` or `\r` instead.
(`\r\n` usually used in windows files, `\r` in Mac files)
You can check it by notice the right-below corner of `notepad++`, where it shows the line endings.
(You can also change line endings through menu `Edit` -> `EOL Conversion`)

Comment: In addition, depending on the OS, you might need to use `\r\n` or `\r` instead.

Comment: @Kartik  Updated. Thanks :)